# NullReferenceException was unhandled C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Visual Studio 2010 - (Windows Forms) in C#

I have this code:

```
private void cbxValuta_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string primo = cbxValuta.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string secondo = cbxValuta2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            double cambio = double.Parse(CurrencyConverter.Convert(1.0m, primo, secondo));
            tbxConvertito.Text = (double.Parse(tbxDaConvertire.Text) * cambio).ToString();
```

I get this error:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: At which string this exception occuring? I think __cbxValuta__ are comboboxes, so you can get __NullReferenceException__ when you take "__SelectedItem__" property value if combobox has no selected item.

Comment: string secondo = cbxValuta2.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: If you are sure that this is where your error comes from then check the values of the selected items that they are not null before you use them.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedItem` return null if no item was selected in a UI element. Try to add check if items has been selected

```
if(cbxValuta.SelectedItem != null && cbxValuta2.SelectedItem != null)
{
       string primo = cbxValuta.SelectedItem.ToString();
       string secondo = cbxValuta2.SelectedItem.ToString();
//       ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have a [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) i the combobox.

> The object that is the currently selected item or null if there is no currently selected item.

Then these lines can fail at `ToString()`:

```
string primo = cbxValuta.SelectedItem.ToString();
string secondo = cbxValuta2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that exception occurs at this string:

```
string secondo = cbxValuta2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It means or cbxValuta2 is null, or cbxValuta2.Selected item is null. Check that you select something in this combobox.

Answer (score 0):

This means that either `cbxValuta2` or (more likely) `cbxValuta2.SelectedItem` is `null`. This isn't strange - if you have a list in which the user can select zero items, a `null` is a very likely value.

You should check for it with an `if` before calling any method (`ToString()`, in this case) on it.

Answer (score 0):

primo is null because cbxValuta has no selected item.